# Convert Oracle RAW of NUMBER to .NET Int64

Tags: arrays, .net, oracle, data-conversion

I have converted this number **735969** to oracle raw this this funcion:

```
UTL_RAW.CAST_FROM_NUMBER(735969)
```

and saved to database.
Then I get saved data from .NET application into byte[] variable **bytesFromDB**.
Content got into variable is

```
byte[4] { 195, 64, 70, 60 }
```

If I try to convert it int with this function:

```
BitConverter.ToInt32(bytesFromDB, 0)
```

It returns a differente number (**1178356419**) infact if I convert **735969** into array with .NET function

```
BitConverter.GetBytes(735969)
```

I get a different byte array:

```
 byte[4] { 225, 58, 11, 0 }
```

This is the [.Net FIDDLE](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rBIXYb)

This is the [Oracle FIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=fc3c2654402a257fb6b0cce0654a0ce9)

Why this???

Which is BAD? ORACLE or .NET??

Comment: Neither is 'bad', different languages just have different internal representations of numbers. Anyway, I have no idea why you are using UTL_RAW.CAST_FROM_NUMBER to store it in the first place but why wouldn't you just use UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_NUMBER when retrieving it?

Comment: Because the data is stored in the database by an external process using the Oracle procedure and retrieving the data from the database directly via NHIBERNATE within the .NET application.

Comment: Oracle does document its internal number format so you could write some code to reconstruct it bytewise - not ideal though as it would be dependent on Oracle not changing that format, however unlikely.

Another alternative would be to create a view over the table in question which performs the conversion (e.g. using UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_NUMBER) and point Hibernate at the view instead. You might also need an INSTEAD OF trigger if Hibernate needs to perform DML on the view.

Comment: I don't understand why you would want to store a number as RAW in the first place.

Comment: Because this is the FIRST step, and the next step will be to encrypt the number. And the only way to encryit it is to encrypt a byte array